# Drawing a Graphical Model from word description of problem

Tags: graph-theory, self-learning, conditional-probability

See the question below and my attempt underneath

..........

[image]

I feel like all of the relationships described in the question are contained in this graph. But later in the question, it asks me to "Construct an efficient junction tree (i.e., with minimally sized cliques)". I don't see any non-trivial cliques in the graph that I've drawn which makes me think there must be a mistake.

What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: You have the self-learning tag but the question parts carry percentage points like this is an exam question.

Comment: It's an old question I found from 2005: http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/course05/asst4gm.pdf